# Quickblox Apps under same account share external ids?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have a dev, stage and production app in a Quickblox account. When testing I'm signing up a new user in production. There are no users in my production app and one user in my staging app.

I'm getting an error saying the external id has already been taken. Looking in the logs I'm definitely connecting to the different apps.

Is this the correct behaviour? Do I have to create a new account if I'm going to be using external ids with multiple apps?

Comment: Please send me a log & steps to reproduce this situation. Also please post a full error message.

Comment: Looks like you can store up to 50 characters (as a string that can only contain digits?) in the Phone portion of a QuickBlox user, and you can repeat that value for multiple users across apps, but you don't get a QA message for trying to add another user with the same number in the same app, which kind of gets you right back to where you started. This limitation is strangely & unwieldy, and I sure didn't expect to be able to log in to any app using a user from a second app's roster. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the correct behaviour. User base are shared between all apps, so you can have a line of apps and all users will be able to use the same login+pass to sign in.

To avoid such things you cab create another Admin panel account and use it for dev/qa envs.

Comment: I don't believe you can create a second Admin account for an Enterprise, on-site installation of QuickBlox. Is there another workaround for use cases like jeh's that require dev and production copies that share external ids where the users shouldn't be able to sign in across apps?